# Invalid value for<path> attribute in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I am a complete newbie in d3.js and I was working around with some code but it's failing to create the path. Can someone help me to figure out what I am doing wrong? 
Link for jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p8S7p/154/

```
   var data = [
    {
        data: [
                [
                    1420815600000,
                    2
                ],
                [
                    1420826400000,
                    2
                ],
                [
                    1420837200000,
                    2
                ],
                [
                    1420848000000,
                    2
                ],
        ],
        parameter: "t1"
    },
            {
                data: [
                        [
                            1420815600000,
                            2
                        ],
                        [
                            1420826400000,
                            2
                        ],
                        [
                            1420837200000,
                            2
                        ],
                        [
                            1420848000000,
                            2
                        ],
                ],
                parameter: "t2"
            }
];
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 80,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 50
},
width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);


var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function (d) { return x(d[0]); })
    .y(function (d) {
        return y(d[1]);
    });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");




var cities = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var t = {};
    t["name"] = data[i].parameter;
    t["values"] = [];

    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].data.length; j++) {
        var m = {};
        m["date"] = data[i].data[j][0];
        m["temperature"] = data[i].data[j][1];
        t["values"].push(m);
    }

    cities.push(t);

}

x.domain(d3.extent(data[0].data, function (d) {
    return d[0];
}));

y.domain([
d3.min(cities, function (c) {
    return d3.min(c.values, function (v) {
        return v.temperature;
    });
}),
d3.max(cities, function (c) {
    return d3.max(c.values, function (v) {
        return v.temperature;
    });
})]);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Temperature (ºF)");

var city = svg.selectAll(".city")
    .data(cities)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "city");

city.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", function (d) {
        return line(d.values);
    });
```

Its meant to be dates on x -axis. How should I  parse milliseconds dates to D3 time format?

Comment: "*How should I parse milliseconds dates to D3 time format?*" - Use `new Date(milliseconds)`, but keep in mind that you can't use `d3.scale.linear` with `Date`, you'll have to use `d3.time.scale` instead.

Answer (score 0):

*In your code*

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function (d) { return x(d[0]); }) //this is incorrect why d[0]
    .y(function (d) {
        return y(d[1]); //this is incorrect why d[1]
    });
```

should have been

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function (d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function (d) {
        return y(d.temperature);
    });
```

Coz that's how you have parsed your data here

```
var cities = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var t = {};
    t["name"] = data[i].parameter;
    t["values"] = [];

    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].data.length; j++) {
        var m = {};
        m["date"] = data[i].data[j][0];//storing this in date
        m["temperature"] = data[i].data[j][1];//storing it in temperature
        t["values"].push(m);
    }

    cities.push(t);

}
```

Working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/p8S7p/155/)

Hope this helps!